# scrollspy animation wont work, nor do i have an idea on how to make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

So i have an assignment due friday to get my portfolio ready and i decided to make it a one page scroll but I can't seem to get scrollspy working without bootstrap (not allowed to use bootstrap) does anybody have an idea how i can get it to work?

i've tried different kinds of js scripts and jquery but i just cant seem to get 'em to work

`https://codepen.io/axelnijsten/pen/VwwLQMV`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Please explore</h1>
        <h1>and</h1>
        <h1>Discover.</h1>
        <br>
        <a href="#works"><input id="works" class= "button-8" type="submit" value="projects" name= " "></a>
    </div>
```

i expect to when i click contact it smoothly scrolls to the contact section

Comment: Just see how bootstrap is doing it ….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Bootstrap or jQuery slideDown() method.

```
<a href="#contact" class="goToSection">Contact</a>
<a href="#CV" class="goToSection">CV</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.goToSection',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown();
    })
</script>
```

**Second Method:**

try jQuery Animate Method.

```js
    $(document).on('click','.goToSection',function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('data-href')).offset().top
        }, 6000);//set second as required
    })
```

```css
 
        body{
        font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
        background-color: #2D3436;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        margin: 0;
        }

        .intro{
        font-size:30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 160px;
        left: 10px;
        h1{
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;

        }
        }

        .navigation{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #202020;
        height: 604px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 550px;


        }

        .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        .navigation{
        align-self: flex-end;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
        div{
        display: flex;
        height: 500px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        }

        a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        padding: 10px;

        &:visited
        {
        color: #EEEEEE;
        }

        }

        }
        }

        .profile-image img{
        border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .button-8{
        color: black;
        background-color: #00CEC9;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border: 2px solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        width: 160px;
        border-color:  #00CEC9;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 25px;
        &:hover{
        background-color: aqua;
        border-color: aqua;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        }

        .divider{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }


        .works{
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: left;
        background-color: #202020;

        }

        .works-sub1{
        display: flex;
        text-align: left;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        img{
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        p{
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        }
        }

        .works-sub2{
        display: flex;
        text-align: left;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        img{
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        }
        p{
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: right;
        }
        }

        .works-sub3{
        display: flex;
        text-align: left;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        img{
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        p{
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        }
        }

        .about{
        display: flex;
        background-color: #2D3436;
        flex-direction: column;

        h1{
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 30px;
        font-size: 40px;
        }
        }


        .about-tags{
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        color: #00CEC9;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .about-content{
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        }

        .contact{
        display: flex;
        background-color: #202020;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 500px;
        justify-content: center; 
        align-content: center;   
        }






        .contact-text{

        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        p{
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }
        }


        .container-icons{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: flex-end;

        i{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #00CEC9;
        padding-top: 150px;
        }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/style.css">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Please explore</h1>
            <h1>and</h1>
            <h1>Discover.</h1>
            <br>
            <a href="#works"><input id="works" class= "button-8" type="submit" value="projects" name= " "></a>
        </div>  
        <div class="navigation" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#works">
            <a data-href="#contact" class="goToSection">Contact</a>
            <a data-href="#skills" class="goToSection">Skills</a>
            <a data-href="#works" class="goToSection">Works</a>
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="res/img/MokeyMokey-DAR.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider">
                <p>HTML - CSS - SCSS - JS</p>
        </div>
        <section id="works">
            <div class="works">
                <h1>Works</h1>
                <div class="works-sub1">
                    <img src="res/img/minesweeper.png">
                    <p>This is an interactible minesweeper box wich i made<br>
                                                        using flexbox.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="works-sub2">
                        <p>This is a chessboard wich i configured together
                                <br>using html and css. This was done with grid.</p>
                    <img src="res/img/chess.png">
                    
                </div>

                <div class="works-sub3">
                        <img src="res/img/minesweeper.png">
                        <p>This is an interactible minesweeper box wich i made<br>
                                                            using flexbox.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="skills">
            <div class="about">
                <h1 class="about-title">What I do (skills)</h1>
            
                <div class="about-tags">&lt;head&gt;</div>
                <div class="about-tags">&lt;/head&gt;</div>
                <div class="about-tags">&lt;body&gt;</div>
                    <div class="about-content">
                        <p>I design websites using Visual Studio Code.<br>
                        CSS, HTML and Sass is what I mainly use to 
                        <br>accomplish these things. </p>
                    </div>
                <div class="about-tags">&lt;/body&gt;</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <div class="contact">
                    <div class="contact-text"> 
                        (contact)
                           <p>If you are interested in what I <br>do you can contact me on the <br>following.</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="container-icons">
                    <i class="icon icon-envelop"></i>
                    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
                    <i class="icon icon-instagram"></i>
                    <i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

see working demo with html css provided by you.

Comment: so i implemented this by replacing my original href's but it doesnt seem to give me the animation

Comment: slideDown() jquery method has animation effects

Comment: you can add time delay also,refer this jquery url ,
https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: https://codepen.io/axelnijsten/pen/pooJLOZ 

so i've implemented the thing you posted as following but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: i think you html structure isn't proper,use bootstrap

Comment: And for use $ you have to include jquery CDN